# regular exp to accept only numbers with comma as the decimal seperator

Tags: php, preg-match

I am trying to validate the european type of data format. I want to validate that it should accept only 2 digits after decimal separator.

```
1.23,61
```

For the above validation i am using the following regular exp ..

```
/^(\d+|(\d{1,2}(.\d{2})*))((\,)\d\d)?$/
```

For testing i tried this number 23%45 it is not throwing the error message.

Any idea why it is not throwing the error message .

Comment: You need to escape `\.`´ s (and grouping is usually done by thousands, not hundreds..). `/^\d+(?:\.\d{3})*(?:,\d{2})?$/`

Comment: i am new to regular exp .. why you are using ?:

Comment: the `(?: .... )` is for when you need parentheses (to make the entire line `,\d{2}` optional), but are not particularly interested in what matched exactly there: it won't populate the subpattern match (try it out for yourself: see what the matches array holds with or without the `?:`). It's just a tiny bit of resource saving.

Answer (score 1):

You have not escaped the dot(.)

```
"/^(\d+|(\d{1,2}(.\d{2})*))((\,)\d\d)?$/"
                 ^
```

needs to be

```
"/^(\d+|(\d{1,2}(\.\d{2})*))((\,)\d\d)?$/"
                 ^^
```